# iOS Dev - how to deploy different builds of the same app onto the same device?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to install different build of the same app onto the same device so I can keep the older builds around to verify bug fixes.  I don't want to modify the bundle id or code sign it with a different provisioning profile each time if I can avoid it.  What's the quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: I think it is *much* easier to just change the bundle ID per build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to modify the Bundle ID but then best to create different targets for a beta so you can just bash out the extra build.

See this for a good guide on it..

http://www.benzado.com/blog/iphonedev-good-practices

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but the best possible way is to change the identifier.

You can easily try `com.yourCompanyName.appName` and change appName...